# Can I instantiate a struct through its base's default constructor?

Tags: c++

Is it at all possible to have the second instantiation work somehow? I've tried combinations of `using` and `= default` but to no avail.

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

struct B : A
{};

A a{11}; // This works.
B b{22}; // "No matching constructor".
```

Comment: Obviously not. Constructors are not inherited.

Comment: No constructor is involved in either initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a constructor for `A`. That's aggregate initialization.

Anyway, you are doomed.  While `B` is-a `A`, there is no way to pass initialization through `B` to `A` without a constructor. There may be some voodoo and witchcraft to make it look like you are initializing `A` through `B`, but it would be better to just write some nice, clean code like a `B` constructor that initializes `A`

```
struct B : A
{
    B(int val):A{val}
    {
    }
};
```

Now obviously `B` has a constructor and

```
B b{22};
```

is valid.

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ 2014 Standard (8.5.1 Aggregates):

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), **no base classes** (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

However According to the C++ 2017 Standard (8.6.1 Aggregates):

> 1 An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with
>
> (1.1) — no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors (12.1),
>
> (1.2) — no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
>
> (1.3) — no virtual functions (10.3), and
>
> (1.4) — no virtual, private, or protected base classes (10.1).

As you can see, the C++ 2017 Standard removes the restriction that aggregates shall not have base classes. So the code will not be compiled by a compiler that does not support the C++ 2017 Standard.

You need to declare explicitly a constructor that excepts an argument for the class `B` yourself.

Comment: Well isn't that cool. There will be some interesting new error messages resulting from that change, but likely worth it. A bit more intuitive.

Comment: Wait, this doesn't exclude having non-aggregate base class, how does that make sense?

Comment: @PasserBy For a base class a corresponding constructor is called using an initializer in the braced list.